# Update query mysql doesn't work

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to update a mysql-entry with the code below:

```
app.post('/updatepw', function(request, response){
    var username=request.body.username;
    var pw=request.body.password;
    var password = bcrypt.hashSync(pw, null, null)
    connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);
        connection.query("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE username = ?",[password, username], function(err, result) {
                                    if (err) {
                                    throw err;
                                    } else {
                                        console.log(result);
                                        //console.log(rows.length);
                                                response.json({
                                                success : true
                                                });
                                    }
                            });
});
```

the console.log for result:

```
{ fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 0,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }
```

Why it does not work? It even throws no error..

Comment: When you execute the same query on your MySql console, does it update anything?

Comment: yes it update it correct, but I need to put with this syntax: `WHERE username = 'testname'`

Comment: So I supose that the problem is that `username` and `password` variables do not have the value you expect them to have. `connection.query` returns an object with the `sql` attribute, so you can log it and check the update statement you're sending to the database.